# Spring Boot: POST submission saves null in database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am building simple CRUD examples using Spring.
I have two entities (Project) and (ProjectExpenditure) and they have M:1 relationship.
My problem is "When I submit ProjectExpenditure via POST, null(for type="text") and 0 (for type="number") are saved" instead of real data sent.

**Entity 1 - Project**

```java
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project  {     
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int budget; 
        
        
    // Business Logic:  Adding Expenditure will minus Project budget 
    public void minusBudget(int expenditure) {
        int leftBudget = this.budget -= expenditure;
        
        if(leftBudget <= 0) {
            throw new NotEnoughBudgetException ("Budget is not enough");
        }
    
        this.budget = leftBudget;
    } 
}
```

**Entity 2 - ProjectExpenditure**

```java
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "project_expenditure")
public class ProjectExpenditure{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private Project project;

    private int cost;

    private String description;

    
    
    // Add Expenditure: Adding Expenditure will minus Project budget 
    public ProjectExpenditure createExpenditure (Project project, int cost, String description) {
        ProjectExpenditure expenditure = new ProjectExpenditure();
        
        expenditure.setProject(project);
        expenditure.setCost(cost);
        expenditure.setDescription(description);
        
        project.minusBudget(cost);  
    
        return expenditure;
    }
}
```

**Repositories**

```java
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ProjectRepository extends CrudRepository<Project, Long> { }
```

```java
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ProjectExpenditureRepository extends CrudRepository<ProjectExpenditure, Long> { }
```

**Service**

```java
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProjectExpenditureService {

    private final ProjectRepository pRepository;
    private final ProjectExpenditureRepository peRepository;
    
    /*
     * Add Expenditure
     */
    @Transactional
    public Long addExpenditure (Long projectId, int cost, String description) {
        
        // Create ProjectExpenditure
        ProjectExpenditure projectExpenditure = new ProjectExpenditure();
        pRepository.findById(projectId).ifPresent(p -> projectExpenditure.createExpenditure(p, cost, description));
    
        
        // Save ProjectExpenditure
        peRepository.save(projectExpenditure);
        
        return projectExpenditure.getId();
    
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```java
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProjectExpenditureController {

    private final ProjectRepository pRepository;
    private final ProjectExpenditureRepository peRepository;
    private final ProjectExpenditureService service; 

    // Add Expenditure
    @GetMapping(value = "expenditureadd/{id}")
    public String addExpenditure(@PathVariable("id") Long projectId, Model model) {
        
        ProjectExpenditure expenditure = new ProjectExpenditure();
        pRepository.findById(projectId).ifPresent(p -> expenditure.setProject(p));
        model.addAttribute("expenditure", expenditure);
        
        return "expenditure/addexpenditure";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/expenditureadd/{id}")
    public String expendtirueSubmit(@PathVariable("id") Long project_Id, 
    @RequestParam("project.id") Long projectId, @RequestParam("cost") int cost, 
    @RequestParam("description") String description, Model model) {
    
        service.addExpenditure(projectId, cost, description);       
        return "redirect:/expendituretlist/{id}";
    }
}
```

**View - addexpenditure**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5">
<head>
<title>Project Management</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"
      th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
</head>

<body style="margin: 15px;">
<div class="container">
        <div th:replace="fragments/title :: title" />

        <div class="form-group">
        <form  class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/expenditureadd/__${id}__}" th:object="${expenditure}" method="post">
        
        <input type="hidden" id="projectId" th:field="*{project.id}" /> <br>
    
        <label for="expenditure" class="control-label col-sm-2">Expenditure</label> 
        <input type="number" id="cost" th:field="*{cost}" class="form-control" /> 
        <br> 
        
        <label for="description" class="control-label col-sm-2">Description</label>
        <input type="text" id="description" th:field="*{description}" class="form-control"/> <br>       
        
        
        <input type ="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
    </div>
        <div th:replace="fragments/footer :: footer" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

After submitting new expenditure, database is updated as below:

id | cost | description | project_id
1  |   0  |     null    |    null

Is there some problem in mapping??

Comment: when you do post, you don't get it as requestParamater. It would be on your requestBody.

Comment: Are you sure that you have a Project with the projectId you provided at ProjectExpenditureService's addExpenditure method. Debug the service method and try to see the values of your parameters, especially projectId. And then be sure that you have a project in the database with that project id.